# MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 444: users_id

Tags: laravel-5.6

estou fazendo um listerner para salvar quando o usuário loga, e imprime o erro do título no models do User.

```
public function accesses()
    {
        // Não esqueça de usar a classe Access: use App\Models\Access;
        return $this->hasMany(Access::class);
    }

public function registerAccess()
    {
        // Cadastra na tabela accesses um novo registro com as informações do usuário logado + data e hora
        return $this->accesses()->create([
            'user_id'   => $this->id,
            'datetime'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Erros de [`MassAssignment`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment) geralmente ocorrem porque os campo inserido não está na propriedade `$fillable` do *Model* ou está protegido pela propriedade `$guarded` do *Model*.

No teu caso é preciso checar se `user_id` e `datetime` estão como *fillable* no model `Access`. Ou então usar o método [`relationship->save()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models) para criar o registro.

Exemplo utilizando `save()`:

```php
public function registerAccess()
{
    return $this->accesses()->save(new Access([
        'user_id'   => $this->id,
        'datetime'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ]);
}
```

Comment: adicionei dessa forma, protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'user_id', 'datetime'
    ]; @fernandosavio o model->save() substitui o create()?

Comment: No model `Access::class` ?

Comment: O create é usado para *mass assignment*, como por exemplo adicionar um array de arrays com vários `Access` a ser criados. O save é usado para salvar um único model.
Então o create exige que o model saiba que campos são permitidos serem inseridos em lote. Por isso o save não checa o campo `$fillable`

Comment: mudei para return $this->hasMany('App\Access'); continua a mesma coisa.

Comment: testei com o save também, o erro continua.

Comment: Tem um detalhe que está me incomodando. Na exception diz que o erro é por causa de um campo `users_id` mas na pergunta está `user_id`.
Checa se não tem um *typo* na tua classe.

Comment: Consegui esste fillable pertence ao model da Access, e não do users. valeu @fernandosavio agora tenho outro erro para tratar. é regra ele colocar o updated_at`, `created_at` no insert?

Comment: Se tu alterar o valor da propriedade `$timestamps` no teu model `Access` ele não faz isso. Olha [aqui nos docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#defining-models)